# How to print array in PHP with unknown number of elements

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a very strange issue with printing out element of an array.

I am attempting to print out some elements of an array inside of a php foreach Here is exactly what the array looks like

```
 [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [body] => dsfgdfgd
            [has_subquestion] => 1
            [is_subquestion] => 0
            [ordering] => 2
            [is_manditory] => 0
            [created] => 2013-01-09 12:06:47
            [parent_id] => 0
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [body] => dfgdfg
                            [has_subquestion] => 1
                            [is_subquestion] => 1
                            [ordering] => 0
                            [is_manditory] => 0
                            [created] => 2013-01-09 11:24:20
                            [parent_id] => 3
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23
                            [body] => gsdgdf
                            [has_subquestion] => 1
                            [is_subquestion] => 1
                            [ordering] => 14
                            [is_manditory] => 0
                            [created] => 2013-01-09 12:56:33
                            [parent_id] => 3
                        )

                )

        )
     [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [body] => dfgdfg
                [has_subquestion] => 1
                [is_subquestion] => 0
                [ordering] => 3
                [is_manditory] => 0
                [created] => 2013-01-09 12:06:47
                [parent_id] => 0
                [sub] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 6
                        [body] => dfgdfg
                        [has_subquestion] => 0
                        [is_subquestion] => 1
                        [ordering] => 3
                        [is_manditory] => 0
                        [created] => 2013-01-08 13:37:07
                        [parent_id] => 5
                    )

            )
```

Notice that the first one has 2 [sub]'s and the second only has one. This is my code for printing them

```
echo count($question['sub']);
foreach($question['sub'] as $s):
    echo '<li>
    <input type="hidden" name="sub[id]" value="'. $s['id'] .'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sub[parent]" value="'. $question['id'] .'" />
    '. $s['body'] .'</li>';
endforeach;
```

this is what it is printing

2
dfgdfg
gsdgdf

8 <--count (which should be 1 not 8)
6 <--each of the following are the first letter/number in the sub array
d
0
1
3
0
2

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there another foreach (or other loop) that contains the one you've posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to update your code to see if the [sub] array is multidimensional or not. I would do it by checking if sub has a key that will only match if there is only a single array:

```
if (array_key_exists('id', $question['sub']) {
    // This is a single array so wrap it in an array so that the foreach logic works
    $question['sub'] = array($question['sub']);
}
... continue as normal with your foreach loop.
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed. I would like to ask one more question. When I do var_dump($_POST['sub']), the only one that was saved was the last one. How could I make sub[id] save multiple ids? O tried name="sub[][id]" and name="sub[id][]" and neither worked. I am guessing that I need to find a different way to save 2 hidden inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Run
print_r($array).

It should also give you your answer in recursive fashion

Answer (score 0):

use is_array() and call the function recursivly ?